# Nom associé à l'adjectif « répandu »

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, substantivation

Quel est le substantif dérivé de l'adjectif *répandu* ? Par example, soit la phrase suivante :

> Le philhellénisme se fut répandu partout en Europe.

Peut-on dire par example :

> Le répandage du philhellénisme fut important.

ou doit-on employer un autre mot, tel que « dispersion » ?

Comment: Un substantif  synonyme de « diffusion », c'est à dire « expansion » convient aussi . L'expansion du philhellénisme en Europe fut importante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tout d'abord, les deux phrases "Le philhellénisme se fut répandu partout dans l'Europe" et "Le répandage de philhellénisme se fut grand" sont incorrectes telles quelles (mais on pourrait dire, par exemple : "...avant que le philhellénisme ne se fût répandu partout en l'Europe").

> Quel est le substantif dérivé de l'adjectif répandu (s'il y en a un:-)!) ?

Je ne vois pas de substantif dérivé de "répandu" qui aurait le sens voulu [1]. Les noms qui me viennent à l'esprit pour exprimer cette idée sont : *diffusion*, *popularité*. Dans d'autres contextes, on pourrait éventuellement utiliser *étendue*, voire *fréquence* (plutôt dans le temps que dans l'espace).

Dans le cas de votre exemple, on pourrait dire :

> La diffusion du philhellénisme était importante/considérable en Europe.

Toutefois, il me semble qu'il est dommage de se forcer à utiliser un substantif. "Le philhellénisme était répandu" est une formulation moins lourde.

[1] "Répandage" [existe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9pandage), mais c'est un terme technique apparemment utilisé dans le domaine des travaux publics... Je ne l'ai jamais rencontré avant aujourd'hui.

Comment: Le passé antérieur serait devenu incorrect??

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez  Passé antérieur d'être : il eut été ; de répandre : il eut répandu. Je ne comprends pas votre commentaire.

Comment: C'est pas super évident de trouver un contexte, mais il en existe dans lesquels “Le philhellénisme se fut répandu partout dans l'Europe” est correct. C'est ce que je voulais dire. Il ne s'agit pas de *répandre*, mais de *se répandre* ici.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Passé antérieur : il se fut répandu, vous avez entièrement raison, autant pour moi. On pourrait par exemple dire "Quand le philhellénisme se fut répandu partout en Europe, ...", mais ce n'est plus tout à fait la même phrase (ce qui m'a poussé à écrire les mots "telles quelles" dans ma réponse).

Comment: *Diffusion* est bien. Quand le phénomène est particulièrement rapide, on utilise aussi parfois *raz de marée*. +1

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter l'autre réponse, en matière d'idées et de doctrines, on peut également parler de *propagation* qui ajoute l'idée de rapidité à la diffusion.  Ça correspondrait assez bien, je crois, au philhellénisme tel qu'il s'est répandu en Europe dans les années 1820, si c'est la guerre d'indépendance grecque que tu as en tête.

Quant au substantif tiré de *répandre*, Godefroy (http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/respandement) a *respandement* avec deux exemples des 15e et 16e siècles :

- Ayant pitié et compassion  des grandes pertes et respandement du sang humain des chrestiens.
- Desireuse d'éviter le respandement de sang.

Le mot n'est plus employé, bien qu'on dise toujours *répandre le sang*.  C'est *effusion de sang* qu'il faut dire maintenant.